# How did Christianity change the treatment of women in the Roman Empire?

Tags: history, early-church, women

Christianity gets a bad reputation in its treatment of women in the modern day. However, when contrasting with the Roman Empire was it an improvement?

Answer (score 2):

Christ certainly dealt with women in his life-time very differently to how they were usually treated in the Roman empire. This, in turn, served as a model for the apostles and all the male members of the Christian faith from the first century onward. The New Testament shows many ways in which women were shown more regard and respect than was the general case with the common-class, whom the Roman authorities sneeringly referred to as 'plebians'.

Consider how Jesus spoke of men and women who were married. He was asked about divorce and he rebuked those who believed the husband could write a certificate of divorce for a wife who displeased him. He referred them to Genesis where God made male and female; that at marriage the two became one flesh so that no man should put assunder what God had joined. He added that laws permitting divorce were concessions due to the hardness of men's hearts (Matthew 19:3-9). He even rebuked those who thought lustfully after a woman, for to do that was just as bad as committing adultery. Where in the world has the bar for faithfulness and loyalty to a wife ever been so set for men?

Consider also how Jesus made no distinction between healing, or even raising to life from the dead, males and females. He also healed a Canaanite woman's daughter.

The disciples proclaimed that, before God, we are all equal; whatever our race, our culture, whether slave or free, male or female, God views us without partiality, and so should every Christian (Acts 17:26 & Galatians 3:28 & Colossians 3:11).

Christian husbands were not to view wives as chattels - their 'property' - but to honour and love them, just as Christ so loved the Church, dying for the Church (Ephesians 5:25-33). That last section of scripture alone would radically transform the treatment of women anywhere, if carried out.

The Christian ethos upholds the biblical teaching that all human beings are of equal worth, that being made in God's image puts a premium on individuality and that we are made for fellowship where one gives themselves to the other in total commitment - never more-so than in marriage.

Now, to what extent might that have changed the treatment of women in the Roman empire? Only to the extent that men submitted themselves to the lordship and headship of the risen Christ, obeying his commands. The more Christian men exemplified this, the more non-Christian men might take notice, but they would only wonder. Noticing the differences would not change their attitudes. They would have to become "new creatures in Christ" before they would genuinely want to treat their wives the way the New Testament requires.